# Webkit lags with large images in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, webkit

i have some problems with webkit (chrome/safari) and Canvas with large images.

For my customer we had to write an animated intro movie with changing images in 80ms per frame on a canvas.

There are 130 frames and we had to put the single images into 4 sprites to reduce the single-request load of the page.

Every sprite size is about 2,5MB and we just slice the part of the needed frame. So far so possible.

don't want to bother you with to much code. But in the end it's just about:

> this.$context.drawImage(img, 0, top, img.width-1 ,(img.height / sequenceCount)-1, 0, 0, this.$canvas.width, this.$canvas.height);

witch is called within 80ms timeouts.

We did that and it works on all major browser. But with webkit every change to the next sprite causes a hard lag of about 400ms.

The same issue was with IE9 but it could be fixed with drawing every sprite once in the beginning

> ```
>    if (Browser.ie9) {
>        for(var x = 0; x < this.sequence[0].sprites.length; x++){                
>            this.draw(this.sequence[0].sprites[x].obj, 0, 1); 
>        }                   
>        this.$context.clearRect(0, 0, this.$canvas.width, this.$canvas.height);
>    }
> ```

(The draw function include just the drawImage function from the example before.)

But with webkit browsers i get still this lagging time of ~400ms.

Yes, the images are preloaded. So this is not the issue.

Any ideas what this could be?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Every time you get the canvas or image width, you are accessing the DOM, which is generally slower than accessing JS memory. You might see an improvement if you store those values on resize, and use the stored value instead.

```
var canvasWidth, canvasHeight, imgWidth, imgHeight;
```

Comment: thx for the answer. Good thinking, but unfortunately this wasn't the solution. Still latency with webkit. Any other ideas?

Comment: wow, it's getting confusing: if i get the width and height of the images from a variable, my IE9 solution for the sprite switch doesn't work anymore. This doesn't make sense at all!